# Insert into temp tables with stored procedure not happening

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I researched this a bit and the closest relatable solution would possibly be this... 
[dynamically creating the #temp table and then used to insert the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542730/dynamically-creating-the-temp-table-and-then-used-to-insert-the-data)

Unfortunately, I am uncertain if it totally applies. Therefore, my question. When I execute the following stored procedure, my temp tables are empty. Of course, if I run each step individually to import data they work. I'm assuming there is a problem with the `EXEC` within the stored procedure. I have 2 temp tables I'm trying to create and insert into and from them assemble my data... Thank you in advance.

```
ALTER PROC [taxes_ext_sp]
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE ##taxes (
        [Apply Date] date
        , [Journal Code] varchar(8)
        , [Journal Ctrl #] varchar(16)
        , [Company] varchar(8)
        , [Description] varchar(255)
        , [Invoice #] varchar(16)
        , [Credit] decimal(20,2)
        , [Debit] decimal(20,2)
        , [Balance] decimal(20,2));

CREATE TABLE ##company (
company_code varchar(32));

DECLARE @company_id Nvarchar(MAX)
        , @db_name varchar(32)
        , @sql Nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @company_id =
company_code FROM ctrl.dbo.comp;

SELECT @db_name =
name FROM sys.databases 
JOIN ctrl.dbo.comp 
    ON sys.databases.name = ctrl.dbo.comp.db_name 
JOIN ##company 
    ON ##company.company_code = ctrl.dbo.comp.company_code;

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ##taxes
SELECT convert(varchar(12),dateadd(dd,(trx.date_applied - 639906),''1/1/1753''),101) --as [Date]
        , trx.journal_type --as [Journal Code]
        , trx.journal_ctrl_num --as [Journal Ctrl #]
        , '+@company_id+' --as Company
        , trx.journal_description --as [Description]
        , trxdet.document_1 --as [Invoice #]
        , bal.home_credit --as [Total Home Credit]
        , bal.home_debit --as [Total Home Debit]
        , bal.current_balance --as [Balance]
FROM '+@db_name+'.dbo.trx trx                       
LEFT OUTER JOIN '+@db_name+'.dbo.trxdet trxdet
    ON trx.journal_ctrl_num = trxdet.journal_ctrl_num
LEFT OUTER JOIN '+@db_name+'.dbo.bal bal
    ON trxdet.account_code = bal.account_code
WHERE trx.date_posted > 0
    AND trx.date_applied >= ''734503''
    AND trx.date_applied <= ''734775'')';

EXEC (@company_id);  **FORGOT TO ADD THIS.
EXEC (@sql);


SELECT * FROM ##taxes;  
--SELECT * FROM ##company

--IF EXISTS
--(
--SELECT *
--FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
--WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##taxes')
--)
--BEGIN
--DROP TABLE ##taxes
--END

--IF EXISTS
--(
--SELECT *
--FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
--WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##company')
--)
--BEGIN
--DROP TABLE ##company
--END

END;
```

Comment: There's no need to use a global temp table (`##`). A local temp table (`#`) created in the outer scope (outside of the `exec`) will be accessible in the inner scope.

Answer (score 1):

You create ##company, but don't fill, and then try to join it with ##company.company_code therefore @db_name can be NULL. Most likely the @sql variable equals NULL.
If you try to concatenate nvarchar fields and one of them NULL, result will be NULL

**EDIT**
Recipes [How to check if a parameter is null or empty sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855331/how-to-check-if-a-parameter-is-null-or-empty-sql)

Comment: I guess what I'm having difficulty with at the moment is when/where to call each variable.  I've been looking at this script too long.

Comment: That returns this request SELECT * FROM ctrl.dbo.comp