# SQL Server variable table in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there anyway i can do something like

Is there anyway i can get a variable into a FROM clause. Like this

```
SELECT * FROM myGetTableFunc(@tableName)

SELECT * FROM EXEC('SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName)

SELECT * INTO #myUndeclaredTable FROM @tableName
```

I think you get the point.

Basicly i will have a few tables with shared common columns like a sorting key etc. In a stored procedure i use these shared columns to work the table and join some stuff and then return it.

But currently I will need a new stored procedure for each table because I can't use a variable in the FROM clause. Is my only solution to turn the whole thing into dynamic SQL?

Things such as `OPENQUERY` `OPENROWSET` will not be possible.

I thought about something like

```
EXEC ('SELECT * INTO #myTempTable FROM ' + @tableName)
SELECT * FROM #myTempTable
```

But `#myTempTable` don't seem to be visible even though i thought it had scope for the entire session.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @TableName = 'myTable'

EXECUTE ('SELECT * INTO #TEMP  FROM ' + @TableName +'; SELECT * FROM #TEMP;')
```

This was just taken from here:

[TSQL select into Temp table from dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534990/tsql-select-into-temp-table-from-dynamic-sql)

And look here:

[dynamically creating the #temp table and then used to insert the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542730/dynamically-creating-the-temp-table-and-then-used-to-insert-the-data)

Comment: Hey i got it working using ##Table, which is very global. How do i solve concurency issues if the SP is running concurrently?

Comment: you could use table hints as seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187373.aspx, most notably TABLOCKX. play around a bit, I'm sure you'll find something.

Comment: Thanks, it seems complex I will throw it in a transaction and set a restrictive isolation level i think. It won't be run that often.